# How to unnest string format in bigquery sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a table like so, and I am trying to unnest a string in the table however been unable to do so.

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"$google_analytics_client_id":"xxxx","fullName":"A","phoneNumber":"+xxxxx","userId":"263175"} |
| 2 | {"$google_analytics_client_id":"xxx","fullName":"B","phoneNumber":"+xxxxx","userId":"263143"} |

I am trying to get the id and userId. The data part is in string.

The current code is as below, where I plan to see what's being returned so that I can select it.

```
select *
from table
unnest(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to retrieve a value from a JSON or JSON formatted string object:

```
select 
  id,
  json_value(data, '$.userId') as userId,
from sample_data
```

Information on JSON functions can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value